# xsltproc : extract value from xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml contents like this i wanted to extract the urc value and it is run value. I was trying to extract the contents using xsltproc. But my command is failing.

```
<urc name="hershyes_one" first-day="20230901" masking="single">
    <jobs>
        <job kind="alarm" run="java">
            <args>
                <arg name="memory">49494</arg>
            </args>
        </job>
        <job kind="nextmark" run="java">
            <args>
                <arg name="memory">49494</arg>
            </args>


<urc name="hershyes_two" first-day="20230901" masking="single">
    <jobs>
        <job kind="alarm" run="python">
            <args>
                <arg name="memory">49494</arg>
            </args>
        </job>
        <job kind="nextmark" run="python ">
            <args>
                <arg name="memory">49494</arg>
            </args>
```

Required output  like this

```
urc: hershyes_one,java 
urc: hershyes_two,java
```

tried with below command, unsure what i am doing wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="//urc">
        sub:<xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="jobs">
        <xsl:value-of select="@run"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: With the samples show, in the context of e.g. `urc`, the `<xsl:for-each select="jobs">` doesn't make sense, it should be `<xsl:for-each select="jobs/job">`, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a well-formed input XML document like:

```
<root>
    <urc name="hershyes_one" first-day="20230901" masking="single">
        <jobs>
            <job kind="alarm" run="java">
                <args>
                    <arg name="memory">49494</arg>
                </args>
            </job>
            <job kind="nextmark" run="java">
                <args>
                    <arg name="memory">49494</arg>
                </args>
            </job>
        </jobs>
    </urc>
    <urc name="hershyes_two" first-day="20230901" masking="single">
        <jobs>
            <job kind="alarm" run="python">
                <args>
                    <arg name="memory">49494</arg>
                </args>
            </job>
            <job kind="nextmark" run="python ">
                <args>
                    <arg name="memory">49494</arg>
                </args>
            </job>
        </jobs>
    </urc>
</root>
```

you can get the result you show by applying a stylesheet like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="urc">
        <xsl:text>urc: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="jobs/job/@run"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notice that this takes the `@run` value from the first `job` only.

Comment: Can you plz suggest me how to use xsl:if condition for urc name, like if urc name is one proceed else no actions,

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. If you change `<xsl:for-each select="urc">` to `<xsl:for-each select="urc[@name='one']">` then only `urc` element whose `name` attribute is "one" will be processed.